# Select a country not visible anymore

Tags: html, css

I am absolute newbie decided to learn html,css, now creating my first social network project and have problems with front end, it works great only with html, but in some point when i wrote more code in style.css select a gender becomes not visible, don't know why, that's my code if you can help me:

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
       v2.0 | 20110126
       License: none (public domain)
    */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
#head_wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid brown;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #99ccff
}
#header {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
#form1 {
  float: right;
  line-height: 100px;
}
#form1 input {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#form1 button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#form1 button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
# content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#form2 {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#form2 input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#form2 select {
  width: 270px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#form2 button {
  width: 270px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
#form2 button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
#form2 h2 {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-family: comic sans ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>My Social Network</title>
</head>


<body>
  <!--container starts-->
  <div class="container">
    <!--Head wrap starts-->
    <div id="head_wrap">
      <!-- Header starts -->
      <div id="header">

        <img src="images/logo.png" style="float: left;" />
        <form method="post" action="" id="form1">
          <strong>Email:</strong>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <strong>Password:</strong>
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="*******" />
          <button name="login">Login</button>
        </form>

      </div>
      <!--Header ends-->
    </div>
    <!--Head wrap ends -->
    <!--Content area starts-->
    <div id=content ">
    <div>
    <img src="images/image.png " style="float:left; margin-right:-40px; "/>
    </div>
    <div id="form2 ">
    <form action=" " method="post ">
    <h2> Sign Up Here</h2>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td align="right ">Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text " name="u_name " placeholder="Enter your name "/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right ">Password:</td>
    <td><input type="text " name="u_pass " placeholder="Enter your password "/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right ">Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text " name="u_email " placeholder="Enter your email "/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right ">Country:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="u_country ">
    <option>Select a Country</option>
    <option>Afghanistan</option>
    <option>India</option>
    <option>Pakistan</option>
    <option>United States</option>
    <option>United Aran Emirates</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right ">Gender:</td>
    <td>
    <select name="u_country ">
    <option>Select a Gender</option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right ">Birthday:</td>
    <td>
    <input type="date " name="birthday ">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6 ">
    <button name="sign_up ">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
    
    <!--Content area ends-->
    
    
    </td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--container ends-->
    
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please don't judge if i do some mistake, or break some rule of stackoverflow, it's my first post.

Comment: I don't see any PHP code here. Just HTML and CSS.

Comment: You have a typo here: `<div id=content">` You're missing the `"` before `content`.

Comment: Thanks, changed, to html, css, back end will be with php, do you know why select a country become not visible? It worked, but when i wrote more code became not visible, don't know why.

Comment: You're also missing `</td>`, `</tr>` and `</table>` after the `Sign Up` button.

Comment: Actually, you have them, but you also have an extra `</form>` before them. That's causing problems.

Comment: After I fixed all these errors, your form works: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2qb4f0xb/

Comment: You should use an IDE, it will identify problems like these for you.

Comment: When i delete style.css it works great, so problem is not with html

Comment: I just copied your `style.css`, it works.

Comment: Select a gender visible without style.css, what mistake i did in style.css?

Comment: It's visible in the jsfiddle with your CSS, so I don't know. Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/lKFq5

Comment: I mean a link to the web page so I can open it up in my browser and go into Developer Tools to see what's wrong.

Comment: To debug CSS problems, go into Developer tools, go into the Elements panel, and find the element that you care about. Then to to the Styles sidebar and uncheck various style settings, to see which of them are causing the problem.

Comment: Solved by changing height in style.css :)

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like that. It's probably dependent on the browser and its default fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple I solved the problem by changing `height` size in style.css `form2 select` from `20px` to `40px`:

```css
#form2 select {
    width:270px;
    height:40px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
```

P.S. Also, thanks for Barmar to find `<div id="content">` typo.